# What's the "Unknown God"?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

In the bonus Hoid scene at the end of Elantris, it says that Hoid looked up at "the Unknown Gods domain". What is that referring to?

Comment: Well, if it is *unknown*... :-p

Comment: Could you add some additional context for that quote; maybe the one or two lines before and after?  I've read Elantris, but don't remember this passage.

Comment: its in a bonus scene at the back of the ten year edition where he talks to a skaze

Comment: @Liesmith - Yeah, it's an added scene in newer additions, and it comes after some of the "extra" scenes from earlier drafts.  Offhand, it's probably a reference to the God Beyond, which is a concept running around more recent Cosmere books as more and more people get used to the idea of the gods, plural, they usually know not being a permanent fixture.

Comment: I don't know, but I think I have a theory. So, if Hoid is looking up, he's looking at the sky, or maybe the universe as a whole. Now, the author has said that (a) the worlds are all in one dwarf galaxy, and (b) Adonalsium created planets in that galaxy that aren't stable on a billion year time scale. And (c) they've hinted that Adonalsium is analogous to the gnostic *demiurge*, which would imply a great power that is not actually the main creator. So what if that one galaxy was created by Adonalsium, and the rest of the universe - directly or indirectly - by the God Beyond?

Comment: https://coppermind.net/wiki/God_Beyond

Comment: @Mithoron why not make that an answer?

Comment: Hmm, Sanderson didn't say this completely openly, I think. it could do though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's just another name for [God Beyond](https://coppermind.net/wiki/God_Beyond). Sanderson [was asked about this scene](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/190-rfantasy-ama-2013/#e4089):

> Windrunner:
>
> Shai refers to an Unknown God, is this at all related to the rocks that fell from the sky that Shai's ancestors carved?
>
> Brandon Sanderson:
>
> For her people, there is a relationship. But watch for mentions of the God Beyond in the books. There is more here.